# Good resources for learning dikduk

Tags: jewish-books, grammar-dikduk, internet

I am really interested in dikduk and am always trying to learn more. Does anyone have any good resources to learn dikduk, preferably online, if not a book/sefer is fine. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16526/759

Comment: It's questionable if this is a "Hebrew language" question, per DoubleAA's link, above. Dikduk is very useful for understanding Biblical and most rabbinical Hebrew. And, some of Gemara's language as well :-) Why don't we have a VTC option for "Aramaic language?"

Comment: Dikduk questions are not on topic but resources for dikduk are?

Comment: @user I agree this post is off topic