# Resources to improve my Hebrew to learn Halachic works?

Tags: torah-study, hebrew, dictionary

My Hebrew is solid - I am able to get around Israel. When I learn works of Halacha (Aruch HaShulchan, Mishna Berura, Kitzur) I am not able to follow due to not knowing words and acronyms. What is a good resource to be able to learn these works without an English translation? A learning dictionary that includes acronyms?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5197/learning-hebrew https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30014/whats-the-most-efficient-method-for-learning-biblical-hebrew

Comment: For the Roshei Teivot themselves, this link takes you to an on-line book that is excellent for the acronyms. You can order a hardcopy from that page if you like it. https://www.hebrewbooks.org/34968

Comment: See the resources mentioned in my answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/138104/11501)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an understanding of grammar and are able to look at a word and see what is the shoresh (the root) and what is prefixes and suffixes, I recommend using a hebrew-english dictionary. There are multiple that should be for sale in physical/online seforim/judaica stores.

Comment: Will the many Aramaic words used in halachic words be found in such dictionaries??